# If I didn’t remember wrongly/If I don’t remember wrongly

Tags: grammar

If someone asked me when did I graduate?

1. If I **didn’t** remember wrongly, it should be on ...
2. If I **don’t** remember wrongly, it should be on ...

Which one is correct? I feel that no. 1 is wrong

Comment: Just drop the negatives:  *If I remember correctly it was...*

Comment: Perversely, "If I'm not remembering wrongly, it was on ..." sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: @Jim I disagree with your first comment. '... remembered wrongly' and ' ... remembered incorrectly' are both ambiguous from a semantic point of view, and I'd say pragmatics in both cases makes the 'misremembered' sense the default. / Though your second comment is totally sound.

Comment: @Jim But [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wrongly) is quite happy with this sense of 'wrongly': << **wrongly** _adverb_ 1 In a way that is incorrect or mistaken.

‘my name is spelled wrongly’ / ‘wrongly interpreted results’ >> There are also numerous internet examples for "remembered it wrongly" meaning 'misremembered ...'. If you're going to come out with bold statements such as 'You remember _incorrectly_ not _wrongly_', you need to add supporting evidence to show that you're not actually answering wrongly.

Comment: @Jim We can delete comments to clear clutter.

Answer (score -1):

> If I didn’t remember wrongly, it should be on ...

This sentence is unwieldy.

> If I don’t remember wrongly, it should be on ...

may be best phrased with the following:

**if memory serves** or **if my memory serves me ˈwell, correctly, etc.** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/correctly)

> If my memory is correct.

Or as also pointed out by another member, **misremember** may fit your needs.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misremember)

> To remember incorrectly